# Why am I getting an exception when trying to create this Screen(window)?

Tags: java

I'm getting an;

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method Screen(int, int, String, Game) is undefined for the type Game

    at Game.<init>(Game.java:15)
    at Game.main(Game.java:94)
```

I switched my program from JGrasp to Eclipse. After copying and pasting all of my codes and classes over, I ran into the error above when trying to run the program. In JGrasp this code ran fine, but for some reason Eclipse doesn't like it.

This is the full code of the Game Class, hopefully this will help show why the exception is happening. Other class I have include, ID, Handler, GameObject, KeyInput,and Player. Each are related to their name. Hopefully this is helpful

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;

public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   private boolean isRunning = false;
   private Thread thread;
   private Handler handler;
   //Creates background window size and holds objects by handler
   public Game() {
     Screen(1280, 720, "Deed", this);
      start();

      handler = new Handler();
      addKeyListener(new KeyInput(handler));
       handler.addObject(new Player(425, 745, ID.Player, handler));

   }

//starts a new thread
   private void start() {
      isRunning = true;
      thread = new Thread(this);
      thread.start();
   }
   // Stops current thread, and catches exceptions
   private void stop() {
      isRunning = false;
      try {
         thread.join();
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
   //Infinite game loop
   public void run() {
      this.requestFocus();
      long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
      double amountOfTicks = 60.0;
      double ns = 1000000000 / amountOfTicks;
      double delta = 0;
      long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
      int frames = 0;
      while(isRunning) {
         long now = System.nanoTime();
         delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
         lastTime = now;
         while(delta >= 1) {
            tick();
            //updates++;
            delta--;
         }
         render();
         frames++;

         if(System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000) {
            timer += 1000;
            frames = 0;
            //updates = 0;
         }
      }
      stop();
   }

   public void tick() {
      handler.tick();
   }
   //Holds extra frames before showing (3 extra)
   public void render() {
      BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
      if(bs == null) {
         this.createBufferStrategy(5);
         return;
      }

      Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
      /////////////////Renders background first, then handlers///////////////////

      g.setColor(Color.black);
      g.fillRect(0,0,1280,720);

      handler.render(g);

      /////////////////Updates graphics////////////////////
      g.dispose();
      bs.show();

   }
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      new Game();
   }

}
```

This is the Screen class is;

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Screen {
   public Screen(int width, int height, String title, Game Game) {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame(title);

      frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
      frame.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
      frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width, height));

      frame.add(Game);
      frame.setResizable(false);
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);

   }
}
```

Comment: There is no such constructor. Paste `Window` class

Comment: Not only is there no such constructor, but you aren't even saving the Window in a variable to use it anywhere.

Comment: Maybe he dont have to due to bad impl ;)

Comment: Paste imports. My bet is that your are importing java.awt.Window.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, a couple of pointers about the code (it would be nice to have more code to work with though):

- No constructor with the corresponding signature exists (`Window(int, int, String, Game)`), you either need to overload the constructor with a version which has this signature or you are using one of the existing ones with the wrong argument types
- Another problem could be that you are not importing things correctly
- You're creating a reference to this Window without storing it anywhere, which serves no purpose, try putting it in a variable (`Window myWindow = Window(int, int, String, Game)`)
- Why are you calling `addKeyListener` twice?

Comment: Okay, I've checked imports, they look good, even tried adding a few that I didn't think I needed, nothing. I then tried putting the window as a variable myWindow, Got same error, and I removed the 2nd key listener(i was messing around with code and forgot it).  I can add more code, but that and the window class is all I have relating to creating a Window. Like I mentioned above this program works fine in JGrasp (I don't know why).

Comment: Without all the code it's hard to say but when I said imports I meant conflicting or erroneous imports (as mentioned in the answer below). The best option would be to put it on GitHub, but even on Pastebin it would be nice.

Comment: I put it on get hub(changed a few things but none the less its the same code) user is mitisme / mit

Comment: I see it, but it seems you changed some stuff, for example Window to Screen? Do you still have the issue?

Comment: yes, another user said that it might be because its trying to get a Java,awt.Window import, so i changed the window class and window in game class to 'screen'

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The method Screen(int, int, String, Game) is undefined for the type Game

 at Game.<init>(Game.java:15)
 at Game.main(Game.java:94)

Comment: Ok I have it on Eclipse, if you replace that line with `Screen myScreen = new Screen(1280, 720, "Deed", this);`, it compiles correctly, which leads me to believe it was importing the AWT Window which was overriding your default package Window constructor all along

Comment: I change it to how you have it, and still doesn't work, this is starting to get really frustrating, ill update the gethub file to show i have it. Like I said I know this works with the other IDE but not eclipse for some reason.

Comment: You forgot the new keyword... Please copy paste the line of code I gave you and try again

Comment: okay that got the screen to pop back up. but it also just gave me a ton of errors. Thanks for all the patience.

Comment: Do you have anymore issues/questions? Otherwise, please don't forget to mark this answer as valid.

Answer (score -1):

I think that you are importing different `Window` class than the one you have pasted eg. `java.awt.Window` double check imports (and to be sure paste those as well se we can check). There is no other explanation for this error.